# Функция IF Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

Необходима формула/скрипт, для таблицы отчетности

- Если значение в колонке A <=899, тогда A*4,9
- Если значение в колонке A <=1499, тогда A*4,6
- Если значение в колонке A >=1500, тогда A*4,4

Чтобы все это выводилось в колонку B.

Comment: Чтобы все это выводилось в колонку B